# K8s Node status using Table format

Tags: bash

I'm just doing small bash script to get k8s node status whether its Ready/NotReady but below script is working fine but output is not user friendly, something i want produce the output in box format.

```
#!/bin/bash

# colors
blanc="\033[1;37m"
gray="\033[0;37m"
magento="\033[0;35m"
red="\033[1;31m"
green="\033[1;32m"
amarillo="\033[1;33m"
azul="\033[1;34m"
rescolor="\e[0m"

listNodes=$(kubectl get nodes | awk 'NR>1{print $1}')
readarray  node_arr <<<  $listNodes

ok=0
notok=0
echo -e "\nSit Down and Wait  \U1F602 :\n"
for i in ${node_arr[@]}
do 
echo -ne "$i ... " 
status=$(kubectl get node $i | grep $i | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ ! $status =~ ^Ready$|^NotReady$  ]]  ; then
        echo -e "\e[1;31mOh Shit !"$rescolor""
    else
        echo -e "\e[1;32mOK!"$rescolor""
    fi
done

echo -e "\nNODE STATUS:\n"
echo "+---------------+---------------+"
printf "|$green%-15s$rescolor|$red%-15s$rescolor|\n" "Names" "Status"
echo "+---------------+---------------+"
printf "|%-15s|%-15s|\n" "$ok" "$notok"
echo "+---------------+---------------+"
echo -e "\n"
```

Current Output

```
Sit Down and Wait   :

node-1.compute.internal ... OK!
node-2.compute.internal ... OK!

NODE STATUS:

+---------------+---------------+
|Names          |Status         |
+---------------+---------------+
|0              |0              |
+---------------+---------------+
```

Expected Output

Instead of printing output into the screen, I want make it inside box.

```
Sit Down and Wait   :

node-1.compute.internal ... OK!
node-2.compute.internal ... OK!

NODE STATUS:

+---------------------------+---------------+
|Names                      |Status         |
+---------------------------+---------------+
|node-1.compute.internal    | Ready         |
+---------------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly changed from Freeman's answer which gave an error due to use of quotation marks. This runs successfully on my Ubuntu/K8s server:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Colors
blanc="\033[1;37m"
gray="\033[0;37m"
magento="\033[0;35m"
red="\033[1;31m"
green="\033[1;32m"
amarillo="\033[1;33m"
azul="\033[1;34m"
rescolor="\e[0m"

listNodes=$(kubectl get nodes | awk 'NR>1{print $1}')
readarray node_arr <<< $listNodes

ok=0
notok=0
echo -e "\nSit Down and Wait  \U1F602 :\n"
for i in ${node_arr[@]}; do
  echo -ne "$i ... "
  status=$(kubectl get node "$i" | grep "$i" | awk '{print $2}')
  if [[ ! $status =~ ^Ready$|^NotReady$ ]]; then
    echo -e "\e[1;31mOh Shit !"$rescolor""
  else
    echo -e "\e[1;32mOK!"$rescolor""
  fi
done

echo -e "\nNODE STATUS:\n"
echo "+---------------------------+---------------+"
printf "|%-27s|%-15s|\n" "Names" "Status"
echo "+---------------------------+---------------+"
for i in ${node_arr[@]} ; do
  status=$(kubectl get node "$i" | grep "$i" | awk '{printf $2}')
  printf "|%-27s|%-15s|\n" "$i" "$status"
done
echo "+---------------------------+---------------+"
echo -e "\n"
```